# How to make P3P play nicely with Azure

Tags: configuration, azure, batch-file, p3p

My co-founder and I are trying to get a **P3P compact policy working with Azure** so that **IE users** can log in to our **Facebook app** which is hosted in a Canvas **IFRAME**.

We've done the work to make the compact policy and have generated all the XML goodness.  That part is done. But we're not having ANY luck getting Azure to do the right thing.

We followed the steps from this link, thinking: "Wow! That looks easy."  Well, it wasn't. After following these steps our Azure server got caught in an apparent endless loop.

http://richardprodger.wordpress.com/2011/04/06/p3p-and-iis-in-azure/

If you've managed to get **P3P and Azure playing nicely together**, can you tell us what you did? How accurate is the blog entry I linked to above?  Any help would be greatly appreciated. We're having our **hard launch** tomorrow (June 6th).

**[EDIT]**

My co-founder think that this issue *may* be related to Azure not bringing over either the *.cmd file or perhaps the *.P3P file. He thinks we may need to tell Azure explicitly that these files are part of the solution.  (Obviously, at this point, we're shooting in the dark.)

Comment: Man, we'd love to get some feedback on this. Our inability to get P3P working on Azure is the only thing keeping us from publishing our App on Facebook...AND GOING VIRAL! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's what we did.  We used "Occam's Razor" to cut through all the noise to identify what appears to be the simplest solution.  Instead of writing code to modify headers and what not, we simply generated the appropriate P3P code using online tools (we already have a privacy policy and terms of use provided by our lawyers) and then we added this to web.config (using values generated by the tool):

```
<httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
      <add name="p3p" value="CP=&quot;IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT&quot;" />
   </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Works great! Now Facebook login works with IE (we only care about IE8 and IE9). Note that this still did not fix the same issue with Safari for the PC.  Don't know if there's a good solution for Safari and cross-domain cookies.